# Trying to populate a multiselect from another file using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am getting my data from another page to populate an input, but I don't know how to populate a multi-select with that data. Here's my multi select:

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="multi-select" id="my_multi_select4" name="experience[]">
    <?php foreach(WorkModel::Work_List() as $work): ?>
         <option value="<?php echo System::escape($work->we_id); ?>"><?php echo System::escape($work->we_name); ?></option>
</select>
```

To populate it, I need to separate the options with the following data from my JSON:

For example: json_required_name

Many times, there's more than one (would have used a foreach loops, but my page loads before the modal, which grabs the data from another page).

Here is my JSON sample:

```
   {"name":"Gev Offshore","description":"","duration":"1","country":"United Kingdom","employer":"gev offshort","start_date":"2015-08-01","job_start":"2015-08-21","job_end":"2015-08-21","requirements":[{"id":"1","name":"IRATA Level 1 Technician"},{"id":"2","name":"IRATA Level 2 Technician"},{"id":"3","name":"IRATA Level 3 Technician"},{"id":"4","name":"Equipment and Hardware Related"},{"id":"5","name":"NDT Aerospace"},{"id":"6","name":"NDT ECI"},{"id":"7","name":"NDT General"},{"id":"8","name":"NDT MPI"},{"id":"9","name":"NDT Radiography"},{"id":"10","name":"NDT Ultrasonic"},{"id":"11","name":"Rigging"},{"id":"12","name":"Rope Access"},{"id":"13","name":"Rope Access \/ NDT Management"}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/1jjps0mv/

Html:

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="multi-select" id="my_multi_select4" name="experience[]">
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
var xreturn = {"name":"Gev Offshore","description":"","duration":"1","country":"United Kingdom","employer":"gev offshort","start_date":"2015-08-01","job_start":"2015-08-21","job_end":"2015-08-21","requirements":[{"id":"1","name":"IRATA Level 1 Technician"},{"id":"2","name":"IRATA Level 2 Technician"},{"id":"3","name":"IRATA Level 3 Technician"},{"id":"4","name":"Equipment and Hardware Related"},{"id":"5","name":"NDT Aerospace"},{"id":"6","name":"NDT ECI"},{"id":"7","name":"NDT General"},{"id":"8","name":"NDT MPI"},{"id":"9","name":"NDT Radiography"},{"id":"10","name":"NDT Ultrasonic"},{"id":"11","name":"Rigging"},{"id":"12","name":"Rope Access"},{"id":"13","name":"Rope Access \/ NDT Management"}]};
$(function() {
    $.each(xreturn.requirements, function() {
        $('#my_multi_select4').append('<option value="'+this.id+'">'+this.name+'</option>');
    });
});
```

?

Answer (score 0):

does your `WorkModel::WorkList()` return json or is it returning an associative array? If it is returning the latter, then your code should be mostly correct with the addition of the following:

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="multi-select" id="my_multi_select4" name="experience[]">
<?php foreach(WorkModel::Work_List() as $work): ?>
     <option value="<?php echo System::escape($work->we_id); ?>"><?php echo System::escape($work->we_name); ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

its necessary that you put the `endforeach;` block for it to know when to terminate the loop, otherwise it will keep repeating the loop over the select end tag.

now, if the former is true, then you want to first convert your data into an associateive array before performing your loop with `json_decode` like so:

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="multi-select" id="my_multi_select4" name="experience[]">
<?php foreach(json_decode(WorkModel::Work_List()) as $work): ?>
     <option value="<?php echo System::escape($work->we_id); ?>"><?php echo System::escape($work->we_name); ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```